# Do downloaded Cylons always have complete memories?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Do the Cylons in the new Battlestar Galactica always have the latest memories present after being downloaded to a new body? That is, do they remember up to the moment of their death?

If so, does that require some kind of permanent link with a Cylon network?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  Upon death, the Cylon's consciousness is downloaded into a new body.  The memories come along with it.

The limitation is that they must be in range of a [Resurrection Ship](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Resurrection_Ship) or the [Resurrection Hub](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Resurrection_Hub) at the moment of death.

Comment: This then implies constant communication with the ship or hub, right?

Comment: @Wikis Maybe.  It might also be a communication burst that happens when they shut down, regardless of whether a ship is in range.  I don't think that was mentioned within the series...

Comment: Depending on how they were killed, it would have to be quick! A burst, indeed!

Comment: @Wikis that depends on how their memories are stored. If it is a genetic storage system then every cell would have all of their memories. In this case you would need to vaporize the entire body all at once in a very, very short amount of time. Not impossible, but it would greatly reduce the number of ways that you could kill a cylon while preventing the upload.

Answer (score 3):

They most definitely remember the moment of their death. This was stated VERY plainly as the justification for the **exceptional** hatred which *Scar* had for the colonials. He had been shot down countless times, and they made it quite plain in the series that he took it extra personal, and that was what made him so vicious and effective.

Unless of course you're talking specifically about the 'skin-jobs'. But the series made it clear the Raiders also resurrected (which does make me wonder why the Centurions didn't).

Comment: The Raiders were biomechanoid, while Centurions appear to be fully mechanical - it could be that "replication" only works for organic functions. Then again, there's no evidence against downloading the experiences of destroyed Centurions into newly manufactured ones.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they do remember.....e.g. the rebel Cylon that killed the human then killed her in new Caprica ...

And no, there is no permanent link.  Three had to transfer the images of Hera via a raider; she couldn't send the info by herself.

Comment: Also, the Sharon who was with the fleet, and had "gone native" said "that's not how it works." Granted, she's a Cylon, so her trustworthiness might be suspect, but she seemed to have proven her true loyalty and trustworthiness.